# How do I create image sequence samples using tf.data?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, data-pipeline

I want to create image sequence samples using the tf.data API. But as of now, it seems like there is no easy way to concatenate multiple images to form a single sample. I have tried to use the dataset.window function, which groups my images right. But I don't know how to concatenate them.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from glob import glob

IMG_WIDTH = 256
IMG_HEIGHT = 256

def load_and_process_image(path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT])
    img = tf.reshape(img, shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 1, 3))
    return img

def create_dataset(files, time_distance=8, frame_step=1):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
    dataset = dataset.map(load_and_process_image)
    dataset = dataset.window(time_distance, 1, frame_step, True)

    # TODO: Concatenate elements from dataset.window
    return dataset

files = sorted(glob('some/path/*.jpg'))
images = create_dataset(images)
```

I know that I could save my image sequences as TFRecords but that would make my data pipeline much more unflexible and would cost tons of memory.

My input batches should have the form N x W x H x T x C
(N: Number of samples
W: Image Width
H: Image Height
T: Image Sequence length
C: Image Channels).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [batching](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) to create batches of size N.

```py
iterations = # 
batched_dataset = dataset.batch(N) 
for batch in batched_dataset.take(iterations):
    # process your batch
```

Here `iterations` is the number of batches you want to generate.

Comment: That is not what I want to do. I want to stack N tensors along my designated time axis. So I want to map a MapDataset to a single Tensor.